# Query slurm jobs through nested SSH connections

Tags: bash, ssh, slurm

I am frequently running jobs on several different clusters and would like to check the status of my SLURM and SGE jobs with a small bash script.

I am able to do so for most of the clusters with

```sh
printf "\n Jobs on Cluster X \n \n"
ssh user@clusterXname bash -c "'
squeue -u user
exit
'"
printf "\n"
```

This gives me an output like this.

Jobs on AXON

```
         JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST  TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
         17251 gpu   CL21E1 user  R    4:38:15      1 gpu02-02
         17252 gpu   CL21E2 user  R    4:37:06      1 gpu02-03
         17253 gpu   CL21E3 user  R    4:36:27      1 gpu04-03
         17254 gpu   CL21E4 user  R    4:35:23      1 gpu04-04
         17255 gpu   CL21E5 user  R    4:34:46      1 gpu04-05
```

However, one server has a nested SSH connection, so I have to SSH from one server to another.

I attempted to nest the code above by

```sh
printf "\n Jobs on Cluster Y \n \n"
ssh user@clusterXname bash -c "'
ssh user@clusterYname bash -c '"
squeue -u user
exit
"'
exit
'"
printf "\n"
```

This gave me a command not found for squeue.

I also tried to put the inner command into a script in the "outer" server and ran

```sh
printf "\n Jobs on Cluster X \n \n"
ssh user@clusterXname bash -c "'
bash job script.sh
exit
'"
printf "\n"
```

In this case I obtained "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." If I do `ssh -t` instead of `ssh`, I do get my desired output but I have to quit the ssh connection.

So what I am looking for is an output like above for my nested ssh connection without having to log out of the server manually.

Many thanks in advance for your help and apologies if I overlooked a thread answering my question!

Comment: You can also setup an [SSH tunnel](https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me (assuming you have keys to ssh to clusterY without a password on clusterX):

```sh
printf "\n Jobs on Cluster Y \n \n"
echo "echo 'squeue -u user' | ssh user@clusterYname"  | ssh user@clusterXname
printf "\n"
```

I've never tried `bash -c` with ssh, but piping in commands as strings always seems to work.

Comment: Many thanks! It works, but I get 3 times "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" before I obtain my output. I think about writing it into a file and deleting the line to print the file line by line in the final step.

Comment: That did the job.

Comment: I think using the `-q` option will turn off most warnings.